# spring framework & asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I heard there is a port of spring framework to .Net framework which is called spring.net.
Anyone can compare those two frameworks? If design the system, which one is prefered or both can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is for Java, Spring.NET is a .NET port of the Java framework.

See the [overview page](http://springframework.net/overview.html) for a summary of the modules it implements.

You can't use both since they are written for different platforms.  If you're designing the system and have the freedom to choose which platform you're implementing in, you can choose either Spring for a Java implementation or Spring.NET for a .NET implementation.

They are slowly getting a bit different, especially with the support for .NET specific things, such as WCF.

If you're going to decide to implement in .NET/Java I would take more into account than simple Spring/Spring.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is the original Java version and Spring.NET is a .NET version. Spring is better, as the .NET port is not as good as the original. For .NET, you are better of with Castle Windsor. The best thing is to use none of the dependency injection containers because dependency injection is not a good design pattern to follow. Neither is MVC. Java has many differences from .NET. .NET has advantage of Web Forms over Java. If you are using .NET, use the best UI platform which is Web Forms. If you are using Java use JSF.

Comment: Lots of opinion there, most of it having nothing to do with the question asked and with no reason for why you think this.